# Stored Procedure outputting String and Cursor

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

Hey guys, I have a stored procedure that outputs just the column of a table.  Instead, I'd like to have 'There are' [column count] 'students.' as an output. Example below.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE active_students (arc in out sys_refcursor)
       as
       begin
            open arc for select count(*) from student;
       end;
```

This generates

```
Count(*)
30
```

would like it to read

```
There are 30 students.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE JSU4290M.active_students (arc in out sys_refcursor)
AS
BEGIN

  OPEN arc FOR 
  SELECT 'There are '|| COUNT(*) ||' students.' AS col
    FROM STUDENT;

END;
```

The double pipe (||) is Oracle's (and now ANSI standard) means of concatenating strings.  Oracle will implicitly convert the integer value to a string.

Comment: @DatabaseDummy: What do you mean by "hide"?  You should be using the column name as a reference, not the position in the resultset because the position could change.  The column name can change too, but it's less brittle.

Comment: @DatabaseDummy: I updated the answer to define the column alias "col".  You can change the alias to other ASCII characters of your choice, otherwise use double quotes to be able to use special characters (not that I recommend this).